# Doctrine and Oracle REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: regex, oracle, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine in combination with an Oracle database. I use platform-specific features heavily, so I already created a bunch of custom DQL functions. But now I ran into a serious problem. To do a LIKE query with a regular expression, Oracle offers the REGEXP_LIKE operator. It looks like a function, but really acts as a relational operator. Unfortunately, Doctrine only allows me to create custom functions, not operators. I cannot use it like a function, because Doctrine requires me to make it a complete expression, e.g. `REGEXP_LIKE(foo, bar) != 0`. But for Oracle that's a syntax error.

As a workaround, I use this contraption in the `getSql` method of my custom DQL function:

```
CASE REGEXP_LIKE(foo, bar) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Looks ugly, though. Is there a better way to get this working in Doctrine??

Comment: If you're using lots of platform-specific features, you don't need the DBAL anyway (because your application isn't portable anyway). You might want to consider using only Doctrine ORM, without DBAL.

Answer (score 0):

`regexp_like` in Oracle is only allowed in the criteria part of the SQL statement; but what you can use is the true Oracle function `regexp_count` in a case clause:

```sql
select col1, col2, -- etc
case (regexp_count(col3, '^Hey$'))
   when 0 then 0
   else 1
end as found
from table;
```

So for your example `REGEXP_LIKE(foo, bar) != 0` would become `REGEXP_COUNT(foo, bar) != 0`